# How to run 2 instances of JBoss EPP (Enterprise Portal Platform) on the same machine

Tags: jboss, portlet, jboss5.x

Is it possible to run 2 instances of JBoss EPP (Enterprise Portal Platform) on the same machine on different ports? JBoss Enterprise Portal Platform version is 5.2.2, which is based on JBoss AS 5.2.0

I'm learning portlets and I need to establish communication via WSRP between 2 portlets running on 2 different JBoss EPP instances.

As a last resort I may end up installing the second JBoss EPP instance on a virtual machine.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

**Update:**

There are 2 options:

1. modify bindings-jboss-beans.xml and set
   `<parameter>${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-01}</parameter>`
2. modify jboss startup script (run.conf, run.bat.conf): add
   -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 to $JAVA_OPTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run 2 instances of JBoss EPP on the same machine, by using differents ports (for example with "run -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01" on the second instance).

Did you encounter issues when doing it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! It works. There are 2 options:
# modify bindings-jboss-beans.xml and set <parameter>${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-01}</parameter>
# modify jboss startup script (run.conf, run.bat.conf): add -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 to $JAVA_OPTS